# Can you pass an object to MVC post action?

Tags: c#, post, model-view-controller, controller, action

I have this MVC post action

```
 [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult PostHere(SomeRandomResult result)
{
 return View();
}
```

Object I would want to pass:

```
public class SomeRandomResult
{
public string firstName {get; set;}
public string lastName {get; set;}
}
```

View:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="first-name" name="firstName">
    <input type="text" id="last-name" name="lastName">
    <input type="submit" value="click me"/>
</form>
```

The question is when I click submit in the form, I want the values in SomeRandomResult to be automatically populated. When I click submit now, the object in the post method is null. How do I get the values from firstName and lastName?

Comment: Instead of first-name, last-name inputs you need to use the HiddenFor on the whole model. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your post body should be some kind of object notation, JSON is popular

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Wick"
}
```

Then your signature becomes

```
public ActionResult PostHere([FromBody]SomeRandomResult result)
```